# Bumblebee in Ubuntu 15.04 (Optirun/Primus) Error

Tags: drivers, nvidia, bumblebee, 15.04, primus

I recently upgraded to 15.04 and after successful installation I noticed that Bumblebee has stopped working. Optirun/primus commands do not detect the gpu anymore (640M LE). Here's what I get when trying to run Steam:

```
$ primusrun steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1428965940)
primus: fatal: Bumblebee daemon reported: error: Could not load GPU driver

[2015-04-25 18:25:59] Startup - updater built Apr 13 2015 15:17:10
[2015-04-25 18:25:59] Opted in to client beta 'publicbeta' via beta file
You are in the 'publicbeta' client beta.
```

My driver is `nvidia-346-updates`.

Configuration files are default. Should I change my kernel driver and library path? (Right now they are `nvidia-current`).

Answer (score 5):

I got it working like that on Kubuntu 15.04 with 340.76:

```
Driver=nvidia
...
[driver-nvidia]
KernelDriver=nvidia_340
PMMethod=auto
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-340:/usr/lib32/nvidia-340:
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-340/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
```

Answer (score 1):

What does "optirun --verbose glxgears" return ?

Edit : I had to change KernelDriver to fit the proper name of the module (I use nvidia-349 so I had to put nvidia-349 instead of nvidia).
Once I dit it, I had to update the XorgModulePath to fit the proper paths to the libraries according to the version of your driver. For me it is :

> /usr/lib/nvidia-349/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules

PS : Thanks to A.B. for his comment

Comment: $ optirun --verbose glxgears
[ 5279.938213] [INFO]Response: No - error: Could not load GPU driver

[ 5279.938230] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

[ 5279.938240] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.

Comment: Could you post your bumblebee.conf ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I solved changing some lines in file `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`:
(I my case I'm using the version 352 of nvidia driver, change this value by your driver version)

```
KernelDriver=nvidia-current
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
```

to

```
KernelDriver=nvidia-352
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-352:/usr/lib32/nvidia-352
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-352/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
```

You can restart the `bumblebee` service with:

```
sudo systemctl restart bumblebeed.service
```

To check the service status:

```
sudo systemctl status bumblebeed.service
```

and you can check the log in `/var/log/syslog` file for any error.

Regards

Comment: You also ensure that the Driver is set to nvidia, like this:  `Driver=nvidia`