# optirun/primusrun cannot load GPU driver on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 15.04, bumblebee, primus

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04. When I run `optirun -vv glxinfo`, I get:

> [  790.194984] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
>
> [  790.195278] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.2.1 starting...
>
> [  790.195292] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
>
> [  790.195299] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file:
>   /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
>
> [  790.195307] [DEBUG] X display: :8
>
> [  790.195315] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>
> [  790.195323] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
>
> [  790.195330] [DEBUG] Accel/display bridge: auto
>
> [  790.195338] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
>
> [  790.195345] [DEBUG] VGLrun extra options:
>
> [  790.195353] [DEBUG] Primus LD Path:
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
>
> [  790.195394] [DEBUG]Using auto-detected bridge primus
>
> [  790.196751] [INFO]Response: No - error: Could not load GPU driver
>
> [  790.196777] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not
>   load GPU driver
>
> [  790.196793] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
>
> [  790.196815] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
>
> [  790.196831] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.

Here is my /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf:

```
\# Configuration file for Bumblebee. Values should **not** be put between quotes

\#\# Server options. Any change made in this section will need a server restart
\# to take effect.
[bumblebeed]
\# The secondary Xorg server DISPLAY number
VirtualDisplay=:8
\# Should the unused Xorg server be kept running? Set this to true if waiting
\# for X to be ready is too long and don't need power management at all.
KeepUnusedXServer=false
\# The name of the Bumbleblee server group name (GID name)
ServerGroup=bumblebee
\# Card power state at exit. Set to false if the card shoud be ON when Bumblebee
\# server exits.
TurnCardOffAtExit=false
\# The default behavior of '-f' option on optirun. If set to "true", '-f' will
\# be ignored.
NoEcoModeOverride=false
\# The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),
\# auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau
\# (See also the driver-specific sections below)
Driver=
\# Directory with a dummy config file to pass as a -configdir to secondary X
XorgConfDir=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d

\#\# Client options. Will take effect on the next optirun executed.
[optirun]
\# Acceleration/ rendering bridge, possible values are auto, virtualgl and
\# primus.
Bridge=auto
\# The method used for VirtualGL to transport frames between X servers.
\# Possible values are proxy, jpeg, rgb, xv and yuv.
VGLTransport=proxy
\# List of paths which are searched for the primus libGL.so.1 when using
\# the primus bridge
PrimusLibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
\# Should the program run under optirun even if Bumblebee server or nvidia card
\# is not available?
AllowFallbackToIGC=false


\# Driver-specific settings are grouped under [driver-NAME]. The sections are
\# parsed if the Driver setting in [bumblebeed] is set to NAME (or if auto-
\# detection resolves to NAME).
\# PMMethod: method to use for saving power by disabling the nvidia card, valid
\# values are: auto - automatically detect which PM method to use
\#         bbswitch - new in BB 3, recommended if available
\#       switcheroo - vga_switcheroo method, use at your own risk
\#             none - disable PM completely
\# https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Comparison-of-PM-methods

\#\# Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]
\# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia-304
PMMethod=auto
\# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current
\# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
\# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

\#\# Section with nouveau driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nouveau
[driver-nouveau]
KernelDriver=nouveau
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```

I already tried reinstalling everything related to bumblebee and nvidia. I've run `sudo systemctl enable bumblebeed`.

`cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch` prints `0000:01:00.0 ON`.

After running `optirun glxinfo` and subsequently `lsmod | grep nvidia`, I get no output, but after `sudo modprobe nvidia-304`, `lsmod` finds the nvidia module again.

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T530 with an Nvidia NVS 5400 GPU and another integrated Intel chip.

I hope I've given enough information for someone to help me fix my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to change the config file by this way: http://askubuntu.com/questions/613915/bumblebee-in-ubuntu-15-04-optirun-primus-error/709013#709013